# Git index file not identical after resetting back - why?

Tags: git, git-index

I'm trying to understand how the git index file works.

I have a local repository with some files, one of them `test.txt`. I was on commit `X` and saved the index file of that commit to a temp directory.

Then I edited `test.txt` added and committed it which created commit `Y`. After that I ran `git reset --hard X` and saved the index file of commit `X` after having reset to it from commit `Y`.

Then I compared both index files (from commit `X` and from commit `X` after having reset to it from commit `Y`) and they were not identical. How can this be ? Is there a timestamp in the file ? as far as I know the index should have been reset to its previous contents (?)

Comment: “Then I compared both index files” How? “the index should have been reset to its previous contents” Then that is what you should be checking. The index as a physical object should be of no interest. All that matters is that lists the right commits, and that’s easy to determine.

Answer (score 2):

> After that I ran `git reset --hard X`

That's what did it: index entries have the hash codes for the checked out content and also the resulting filesystem timestamps in the work tree. When you did `git reset --hard` it updated the work tree, so those files have identical content but more recent timestamps than the previous checkout of the same content.

Answer (score 1):

What does it matter what the index *file* is like? All that's important is what version of what files it *lists*. You can find that out with `ls-files`.

Example:

```
$ git init
$ echo "howdy" > howdy.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "root"
$ echo "bonjour" >> howdy.txt
$ echo "byebye" > byebye.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "first"
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 3abe061d90cd975b4bef1fa702caec7c0f320b29 0   byebye.txt
100644 e1f6537eb149ccead2e53cbf2da40291c07d904a 0   howdy.txt
```

OK, so those are the "contents" of the index. Now let's make a change and a new commit:

```
$ echo "extra line" >> howdy.txt
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "second"
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 3abe061d90cd975b4bef1fa702caec7c0f320b29 0   byebye.txt
100644 1ad49f2d780a4b46f68dd9bb1571c65ffc1dc660 0   howdy.txt
```

And now let's reset:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 3abe061d90cd975b4bef1fa702caec7c0f320b29 0   byebye.txt
100644 e1f6537eb149ccead2e53cbf2da40291c07d904a 0   howdy.txt
```

As you can see, the index is "identical" to what it was, in the only sense that matters.